# Does this EXPLAIN indicate why Postgres query so slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, explain

I perform a number of querys on a Postgres SQL database, and most perform very quickly, but one performs really slow. Even when testing so that I only limit to 100 records form the main release table (all queries are based on the release table) it takes **50 seconds**, whereas all the other queries take less than a second

Here are they key tables containign more than a few rows

**l_artist_recording**

```
     Column     |           Type           |                            Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('l_artist_recording_id_seq'::regclass)
 link           | integer                  | not null
 entity0        | integer                  | not null
 entity1        | integer                  | not null
 edits_pending  | integer                  | not null default 0
 last_updated   | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 link_order     | integer                  | not null default 0
 entity0_credit | text                     | not null default ''::text
 entity1_credit | text                     | not null default ''::text
Indexes:
    "l_artist_recording_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "l_artist_recording_idx_uniq" UNIQUE, btree (entity0, entity1, link, link_order)
    "l_artist_recording_entity1_idx" btree (entity1)
    "l_artist_recording_idx_entity1" btree (entity1)
    "l_artist_recording_link" btree (link)
Check constraints:
    "l_artist_recording_edits_pending_check" CHECK (edits_pending >= 0)
    "l_artist_recording_link_order_check" CHECK (link_order >= 0)
```

**recording_release**

```
Table "musicbrainz.recording_release"
    Column    |  Type   | Modifiers
--------------+---------+-----------
 recording_id | integer | not null
 release_id   | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "recording_release_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (recording_id, release_id)
    "recording_release_recording_id" btree (recording_id)
    "recording_release_release_id" btree (release_id)
```

**artist**

```
      Column      |           Type           |                      Modifiers
------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer                  | not null default nextval('artist_id_seq'::regclass)
 gid              | uuid                     | not null
 name             | character varying        | not null
 sort_name        | character varying        | not null
 begin_date_year  | smallint                 |
 begin_date_month | smallint                 |
 begin_date_day   | smallint                 |
 end_date_year    | smallint                 |
 end_date_month   | smallint                 |
 end_date_day     | smallint                 |
 type             | integer                  |
 area             | integer                  |
 gender           | integer                  |
 comment          | character varying(255)   | not null default ''::character varying
 edits_pending    | integer                  | not null default 0
 last_updated     | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 ended            | boolean                  | not null default false
 begin_area       | integer                  |
 end_area         | integer                  |
Indexes:
    "artist_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "artist_idx_gid" UNIQUE, btree (gid)
    "artist_idx_area" btree (area)
    "artist_idx_begin_area" btree (begin_area)
    "artist_idx_end_area" btree (end_area)
    "artist_idx_lower_name" btree (lower(name::text))
    "artist_idx_name" btree (name)
    "artist_idx_sort_name" btree (sort_name)
Check constraints:
    "artist_edits_pending_check" CHECK (edits_pending >= 0)
    "artist_ended_check" CHECK ((end_date_year IS NOT NULL OR end_date_month IS NOT NULL OR end_date_day IS NOT NULL) AND ended = true OR end_date_year IS NULL AND end_date_month IS NULL AND end_date_day IS NULL)
```

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.entity1 as recordingId, 
t1.entity0 as artistId, 
t2.id as linkid, 
t3.name as type, 
t4.name, 
t4.sort_name,  
t4.gid,  
t9.latinname as latinName,   
t9.islatin,   
t7.name as linkattribute,  
at.name as artistType   
FROM l_artist_recording t1   
INNER JOIN link t2 on t1.link=t2.id   
INNER JOIN link_type t3 on t2.link_type=t3.id   
AND (t3.name='performer' OR t3.name='instrument' OR t3.name='vocal' )   
LEFT JOIN link_attribute t6   
ON t6.link = t2.id  
LEFT JOIN link_attribute_type t7   
ON t6.attribute_type = t7.id  
INNER JOIN artist t4 on t1.entity0=t4.id   
INNER JOIN artist_latin t9 on t9.id=t4.id   
LEFT JOIN artist_type at on t4.type=at.id  
INNER JOIN recording t5 on t1.entity1=t5.id   
INNER JOIN recording_release rr ON t5.id = rr.recording_id  
WHERE rr.release_id BETWEEN ? AND ?   
ORDER BY recordingId, artistId, linkid, linkattribute";
```

I have checked all the tables to ensure they have an index on whatever field is being joined, in a few cases it was missing so I added. I also ran `VACUUM ANALYZE` on those tables but it made no difference.

This is my explain  (analyze, buffers) output

```
                                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=336796.42..336797.05 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=93229.472..93233.580 rows=1271 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5215 read=97399, temp read=138990 written=138908
   ->  Sort  (cost=336796.42..336796.48 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=93229.468..93230.653 rows=1286 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t1.entity1, t1.entity0, t2.id, t7.name, t3.name, t4.name, t4.sort_name, t4.gid, t9.latinname, t9.islatin, at.name
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 245kB
         Buffers: shared hit=5215 read=97399, temp read=138990 written=138908
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=334176.87..336795.96 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=91632.892..93226.628 rows=1286 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=5197 read=97399, temp read=138990 written=138908
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=334176.44..336665.45 rows=21 width=103) (actual time=91632.830..93211.718 rows=1286 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (rr.recording_id = t1.entity1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=151 read=97315, temp read=138990 written=138908
                     ->  Index Scan using recording_release_release_id on recording_release rr  (cost=0.44..1833.24 rows=891 width=4) (actual time=0.028..2.371 rows=825 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((release_id >= 1) AND (release_id <= 100))
                           Buffers: shared hit=130 read=121
                     ->  Hash  (cost=333485.62..333485.62 rows=55230 width=99) (actual time=91631.881..91631.881 rows=3813157 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 8192  Batches: 32 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 20481kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=21 read=97194, temp read=61835 written=116275
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=132574.41..333485.62 rows=55230 width=99) (actual time=12380.770..84898.987 rows=3813157 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (t4.type = at.id)
         .....
```

and that is the crux of the matte, is my EXPLAIN telling me the query will perform badly or not I cannot tell, although I do notice some sequential scans that I take to be bad.

To get some idea of database size the RELEASE table contains just over two million records

How can I improve the performance of this query ?

**Update**
Nicks suggestion worked

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.entity1 as recordingId,   
t1.entity0 as artistId,   t2.id as linkid,   
t3.name as type,   
t4.name,   
t4.sort_name,    
t4.gid,    
t9.latinname as latinName,   
t9.islatin,   
t7.name as linkattribute,   
at.name as artistType   
FROM   
(    
    SELECT t1.*    
    FROM recording_release rr    
    INNER JOIN l_artist_recording t1 on t1.entity1=rr.recording_id    
    WHERE rr.release_id between ? AND ?   
) AS t1   
INNER JOIN link t2 on t1.link=t2.id   
INNER JOIN link_type t3 on t2.link_type=t3.id   
AND (t3.name='performer' OR t3.name='instrument' OR t3.name='vocal' )  
LEFT JOIN link_attribute t6   ON t6.link = t2.id  
LEFT JOIN link_attribute_type t7   ON t6.attribute_type = t7.id   
INNER JOIN artist t4 on t1.entity0=t4.id   
INNER JOIN artist_latin t9 on t9.id=t4.id   
LEFT JOIN artist_type at on t4.type=at.id   
ORDER BY recordingId, artistId, linkid, linkattribute;
```

**Update 2**
Okay it worked fine when doing 1 to 100 records but that was only a temporary limit for testing because it was running so slow.

When increased to 1 to 1000 (which is still much less than the normal batch size of 20, 000) it took **13 seconds**, whilst that is much better than before it is still much slower than all the other queries tat al take less than a second even at 1000 records.

So it seems there is still some underlying issue here causing an issue

**Explain for new Sql 1 to 100 queries**

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=49182.37..49183.00 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=917.393..920.229 rows=1271 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=21647
   ->  Sort  (cost=49182.37..49182.43 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=917.390..918.206 rows=1286 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t1.entity1, t1.entity0, t2.id, t7.name, t3.name, t4.name, t4.sort_name, t4.gid, t9.latinname, t9.islatin, at.name
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 245kB
         Buffers: shared hit=21647
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9574.07..49181.91 rows=21 width=99) (actual time=861.507..915.523 rows=1286 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (t4.type = at.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=21629
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9572.93..49180.54 rows=21 width=96) (actual time=861.479..913.388 rows=1286 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=21628
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9572.50..49028.19 rows=21 width=86) (actual time=861.455..904.887 rows=1286 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=16484
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=9572.08..48875.86 rows=21 width=34) (actual time=861.419..895.695 rows=1286 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (t6.attribute_type = t7.id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=11340
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9530.00..48833.50 rows=21 width=28) (actual time=859.792..891.958 rows=1286 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=11320
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=9529.58..48752.33 rows=21 width=24) (actual time=859.709..884.275 rows=1232 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: (t1.link = t2.id)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=7623
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..39213.26 rows=2708 width=12) (actual time=0.043..12.256 rows=2559 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=4005
                                                   ->  Index Scan using recording_release_release_id on recording_release rr  (cost=0.44..1833.24 rows=891 width=4) (actual time=0.020..1.477 rows=825 loops=1)
                                                         Index Cond: ((release_id >= 1) AND (release_id <= 100))
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=251
                                                   ->  Index Scan using l_artist_recording_entity1_idx on l_artist_recording t1  (cost=0.43..41.84 rows=11 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=3 loops=825)
                                                         Index Cond: (entity1 = rr.recording_id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=3754
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=9487.20..9487.20 rows=3321 width=16) (actual time=859.601..859.601 rows=179079 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8069kB
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=3618
                                                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.60..9487.20 rows=3321 width=16) (actual time=0.095..721.936 rows=179079 loops=1)
                                                         Hash Cond: (t2.link_type = t3.id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=3618
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on link t2  (cost=0.00..7842.74 rows=423374 width=8) (actual time=0.003..286.605 rows=423374 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=3609
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=23.55..23.55 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.075..0.075 rows=6 loops=1)
                                                               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=9
                                                               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on link_type t3  (cost=12.84..23.55 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.044..0.068 rows=6 loops=1)
                                                                     Recheck Cond: (((name)::text = 'performer'::text) OR ((name)::text = 'instrument'::text) OR ((name)::text = 'vocal'::text))
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=9
                                                                     ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12.84..12.84 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                 Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'performer'::text)
                                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                 Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'instrument'::text)
                                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                 Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'vocal'::text)
                                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=2
                                       ->  Index Only Scan using link_attribute_pkey on link_attribute t6  (cost=0.42..3.84 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1232)
                                             Index Cond: (link = t2.id)
                                             Heap Fetches: 0
                                             Buffers: shared hit=3697
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=29.81..29.81 rows=981 width=14) (actual time=1.602..1.602 rows=981 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 47kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=20
                                       ->  Seq Scan on link_attribute_type t7  (cost=0.00..29.81 rows=981 width=14) (actual time=0.011..0.827 rows=981 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=20
                           ->  Index Scan using artist_pkey on artist t4  (cost=0.43..7.24 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1286)
                                 Index Cond: (id = t1.entity0)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=5144
                     ->  Index Scan using artist_latin_pkey on artist_latin t9  (cost=0.43..7.24 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1286)
                           Index Cond: (id = t1.entity0)
                           Buffers: shared hit=5144
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=11) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=6 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
                     ->  Seq Scan on artist_type at  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=6 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=1
 Total runtime: 922.078 ms
(75 rows)
```

**Explain for new Sql 1 to 1000 queries**

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=213157.51..213163.93 rows=214 width=99) (actual time=27763.225..27797.833 rows=11003 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=186910 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
   ->  Sort  (cost=213157.51..213158.04 rows=214 width=99) (actual time=27763.223..27774.013 rows=17087 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t1.entity1, t1.entity0, t2.id, t7.name, t3.name, t4.name, t4.sort_name, t4.gid, t9.latinname, t9.islatin, at.name
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3291kB
         Buffers: shared hit=186910 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=184770.48..213149.22 rows=214 width=99) (actual time=26757.748..27732.727 rows=17087 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (t4.type = at.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=186892 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=184769.35..213145.63 rows=214 width=96) (actual time=26757.717..27705.989 rows=17087 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=186891 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=184768.92..211593.13 rows=214 width=86) (actual time=26757.687..27597.879 rows=17087 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=118447 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=184768.49..210040.78 rows=214 width=34) (actual time=26757.646..27484.937 rows=17087 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (t6.attribute_type = t7.id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=50080 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=184726.42..209995.76 rows=214 width=28) (actual time=26756.055..27456.678 rows=17087 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=50060 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=184726.00..209168.66 rows=214 width=24) (actual time=26756.000..27370.294 rows=14507 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: (rr.recording_id = t1.entity1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=6525 read=59034, temp read=26077 written=26047
                                             ->  Index Scan using recording_release_release_id on recording_release rr  (cost=0.44..17820.60 rows=8992 width=4) (actual time=0.019..13.477 rows=10502 loops=1)
                                                   Index Cond: ((release_id >= 1) AND (release_id <= 1000))
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=2416
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=184035.19..184035.19 rows=55230 width=24) (actual time=26755.546..26755.546 rows=3637342 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 8192  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 20481kB
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=4109 read=59034, temp written=17302
                                                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=9528.71..184035.19 rows=55230 width=24) (actual time=850.530..23553.356 rows=3637342 loops=1)
                                                         Hash Cond: (t1.link = t2.id)
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=4109 read=59034
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on l_artist_recording t1  (cost=0.00..129942.91 rows=7041791 width=12) (actual time=0.027..4867.525 rows=7041650 loops=1)
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=491 read=59034
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=9487.20..9487.20 rows=3321 width=16) (actual time=850.421..850.421 rows=179079 loops=1)
                                                               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8069kB
                                                               Buffers: shared hit=3618
                                                               ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.60..9487.20 rows=3321 width=16) (actual time=0.100..713.303 rows=179079 loops=1)
                                                                     Hash Cond: (t2.link_type = t3.id)
                                                                     Buffers: shared hit=3618
                                                                     ->  Seq Scan on link t2  (cost=0.00..7842.74 rows=423374 width=8) (actual time=0.003..281.553 rows=423374 loops=1)
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=3609
                                                                     ->  Hash  (cost=23.55..23.55 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=6 loops=1)
                                                                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                                                           Buffers: shared hit=9
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on link_type t3  (cost=12.84..23.55 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.042..0.070 rows=6 loops=1)
                                                                                 Recheck Cond: (((name)::text = 'performer'::text) OR ((name)::text = 'instrument'::text) OR ((name)::text = 'vocal'::text))
                                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=9
                                                                                 ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12.84..12.84 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                                       Buffers: shared hit=6
                                                                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'performer'::text)
                                                                                             Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'instrument'::text)
                                                                                             Buffers: shared hit=2
                                                                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_type_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'vocal'::text)
                                                                                             Buffers: shared hit=2
                                       ->  Index Only Scan using link_attribute_pkey on link_attribute t6  (cost=0.42..3.84 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=14507)
                                             Index Cond: (link = t2.id)
                                             Heap Fetches: 0
                                             Buffers: shared hit=43535
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=29.81..29.81 rows=981 width=14) (actual time=1.568..1.568 rows=981 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 47kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=20
                                       ->  Seq Scan on link_attribute_type t7  (cost=0.00..29.81 rows=981 width=14) (actual time=0.010..0.785 rows=981 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=20
                           ->  Index Scan using artist_pkey on artist t4  (cost=0.43..7.24 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=17087)
                                 Index Cond: (id = t1.entity0)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=68367
                     ->  Index Scan using artist_latin_pkey on artist_latin t9  (cost=0.43..7.24 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=17087)
                           Index Cond: (id = t1.entity0)
                           Buffers: shared hit=68444
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.06..1.06 rows=6 width=11) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=6 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
                     ->  Seq Scan on artist_type at  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=6 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=6 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=1
 Total runtime: 27805.582 ms
(78 rows)
```

**Update 3**

Based on Patricks suggestion this query runs fine for 100 records, for 1000 it is still slow but slight quicker at 12 seconds

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.entity1 as recordingId,    
t1.entity0 as artistId,    
t2.id as linkid,    
t3.name as type,    
t4.name,    
t4.sort_name,     
t4.gid,     
t9.latinname as latinName,      
t9.islatin,      
t7.name as linkattribute,    
at.name as artistType    
FROM recording_release rr   
INNER JOIN l_artist_recording t1 on t1.entity1=rr.recording_id    
AND rr.release_id between ? AND ?   
INNER JOIN link t2 on t1.link=t2.id      
INNER JOIN link_type t3 on t2.link_type=t3.id    
AND (t3.name='performer' OR t3.name='instrument' OR t3.name='vocal' )    
LEFT JOIN link_attribute t6    
ON t6.link = t2.id    
LEFT JOIN link_attribute_type t7    
ON t6.attribute_type = t7.id    
INNER JOIN artist t4 on t1.entity0=t4.id    
INNER JOIN artist_latin t9 on t9.id=t4.id    
LEFT JOIN artist_type at on t4.type=at.id    
ORDER BY recordingId, artistId, linkid, linkattribute;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain instances, the database statistics can't easily determine the number of rows that will be returned for a between query when using placeholders.  As a result a non-optimal explain plan is sometimes returned.

If you update your query to a subselect on the inner join, you should see better results.

```
Inner Join (select <your cols> from recording_release where release_id between ? and ?) rr
```

Comment: well it worked when selecting 1 to 100 releases, but just going up to 1000 releases severely impacted performance. I have added query plan for new query for 1 to 100 and 1 to 1000 if yo have any ideas ?

Comment: What was the performance difference?  Based on your explain plan you are going from ~1,200 rows to ~12,000 an order of magnitude larger.

Comment: It went from less than a second to 12 seconds (100 releases to 1000 releases) so on that basis would be too slow at higher values, however good news when I increased to 20,000 releases it actually only went upto 26 seconds, and some of the other queries were similar length so that is acceptable performance after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a condition (filter) in the `JOIN` clause can help optimizer deficiencies, and I find it short and more readable than a subquery.

```
INNER JOIN link_type t3 on t2.link_type=t3.id    
             AND (t3.name='performer' OR t3.name='instrument' OR t3.name='vocal' )
```

Comment: Good point but your example is wrong as this is what I started with you shod be putting moving the WHERE RELEASE BETWEEN part

Comment: For postgres, this is just not true. (join) Conditions can be put anywhere, the resulting query plan will be the same. (except for LEFT JOINs, of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
        --Major rework a la @joop
WITH selected AS (
        SELECT ar.entity1, ar.entity0, ar.link
        FROM l_artist_recording ar
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM recording_release rr
                WHERE ar.entity1=rr.recording_id
                AND rr.release_id between ? AND ?
                )
        )
SELECT sel.entity1 as recordingId
        , sel.entity0 as artistId
        , lnk.id as linkid
        , atyp.name as artistType
        , rol.name as roletype
        , art.name as artname
        , art.sort_name
        , art.gid
        , lat.latinname as latinName
        , lat.islatin
        , att.name as linkattribute
FROM selected sel
JOIN artist art on art.id = sel.entity0
JOIN artist_latin lat on lat.id= art.id
JOIN link lnk on lnk.id = sel.link
JOIN link_type rol on rol.id = lnk.link_type AND rol.name IN ('performer', 'instrument', 'vocal' )

LEFT JOIN link_attribute la ON la.link = lnk.id
/*LEFT*/ JOIN link_attribute_type att ON att.id = la.attribute_type

LEFT JOIN artist_type atyp on atyp.id = art.type
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
        ;

-- The same without the CTE:

SELECT sel.entity1 as recordingId
        , sel.entity0 as artistId
        , lnk.id as linkid
        , atyp.name as artistType
        , rol.name as roletype
        , art.name as artname
        , art.sort_name
        , art.gid
        , lat.latinname as latinName
        , lat.islatin
        , att.name as linkattribute
FROM    (
        SELECT ar.entity1, ar.entity0  , ar.link
        FROM l_artist_recording ar
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM recording_release rr
                WHERE ar.entity1=rr.recording_id
                AND rr.release_id between ? AND ?
                )
        ) sel
JOIN artist art on art.id = sel.entity0
JOIN artist_latin lat on lat.id= art.id
JOIN link lnk on lnk.id = sel.link
JOIN link_type rol on rol.id = lnk.link_type AND rol.name IN ('performer', 'instrument', 'vocal' )

LEFT JOIN link_attribute la ON la.link = lnk.id
/*LEFT*/ JOIN link_attribute_type att ON att.id = la.attribute_type

LEFT JOIN artist_type atyp on atyp.id = art.type
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
        ;
```

---

- The query can benefit from the CTE if the selected set in the CTE is relatively small.
- if you get duplicates, there is something wrong with your query(a missed JOIN condition for one of the lookup tables ) instead of adding `DISTINCT` you should solve it by adding this condition.